# How to publish TF frame by Pylon ROS?

Tags: ros-noetic

I am using the package pylon_ros_camera for Balser camera, the OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and the ROS distro is Noetic.

Here is the link: https://github.com/basler/pylon-ros-camera

In `config/defualt.yaml`, the description for first parameter `camera_frame` it says "The tf frame under which the images were published".
However I don't see the tf frame with RViz or tf_monitor when I am running program.
Here is how I run the program: `roslaunch pylon_camera pylon_camera_node.launch`

My question is "how do I use this package to publish tf frame?"

Comment: `default.yaml` or `defualt.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is too set the frame_id value embedded in the published data. That frame_id should match one that is being published by another piece of the system, usually robot_state_publisher based on the URDF description of the robot. Then you can use rviz to view the data relative to any other connected frame in the system.

Too directly answer your question. You this package does not publish the transforms, and shouldn't.